# How can I restore a Dell Latitude E6410 back to Factory Settings/By pass Bit Locker Encryption?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, bios, encryption, dell-latitude

I have just been given a Dell Latitude E6410.  The Laptop has not been used in a while, though still loads etc.  The Laptop has the Bit Locker Encryption installed.  Neither myself nor the original owner has is able to recall the Password.

Is there a way to bypass the Bit Locker?  Ideally, I would like to reset the entire Laptop back to Factory Settings.  I have tried 'F8' and 'F12' etc upon startup, however I am unable to find the relevant options.

Furthermore, I would like to add that I am unable to get through to Windows, due to the Bit Locker, so cannot access Control Panel etc.  Maybe there is a way through BIOS etc?

Is anyone able to provide any assistance on this matter?

Comment: You should simply, remove the HDD allowing the laptop to automatically go to the firmware settings, allowing to access the boot configuration so you can change the boot order.  This, of course, presumes no password was set there.  Once you have changed the boot order, connect the HDD to the laptop, and format it within the installation environment of an OS.

Comment: You will need a Dell W7 OS cd/dvd to reinstall W7 , there is no recovery partition on that model. There is a specific order to install drivers after W7 is installed clean, Instructions can be found in the Re-Image guide at this link....https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/product/latitude-e6410/manuals

Comment: Drivers can also be found at the link above.

Comment: Dell W7 discs can be found on ebay for cheap since they do not need a w7 product key to install and are pre-activated when installed on Dell hardware, therefore they have much less value that one that comes with a key. I have several laying around myself.

Comment: @Ramhound: I am able to change the Boot order, without removing the HDD. When I do this, I cannot get past the initial Boot phase. How am I able to reformat the HDD? I have gone to the Factory Restore options but the option does not seem to be there.

Comment: Your problem cannot be solved by the factory restore option, you need a Windows 7 ISO, and to format the HDD and delete all partitions

Comment: @Ramhound: So I need to purchase a Windows 7 ISO Disk. Once I place the Disk into the Laptop, it will by pass the Bit Locker screen and allow me to wipe the Laptop and reinstall Windows? If this is the case, could I insert the HDD into another Dell Laptop and purchase a digital Windows ISO? Then download it to the HDD. Then place the HDD into the actual Laptop I want to wipe?

Comment: Windows 7 ISOs can be downloaded for free off the internet.  Since only one edition of Windows 7 supports BitLocker be sure you download the correct edition.

Comment: @Ramhound: For free? I would need a Product Key though, right, which requires a purchased version? If I place the HDD into another Dell Laptop, wouldn't the Bit Locker still appear?

Comment: [Nope; OEM Windows 7 disks (free) can be created by modifying a single text file. You made no me mention the license key wasn’t accessible...](https://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-can-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft/1046062#1046062)

Comment: @Ramhound: I have just found the Product Key inside the Laptop itself. So I will try the download. Just not certain how transferring the HDD to another Laptop, will bypass the Bit Locker screen but will see what happens and update accordingly. Thanks for your assistance on this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81448/discussion-between-ramhound-and-craig).

Comment: Thanks for your time.  I am currently on the Live Chat now.